# Remove wordpress plugin js and css files from Inappropriate pages

Tags: wordpress, optimization, plugins, pagespeed, contact-form-7

I use Contact Form 7 wordpress plugin only at 2 pages at my website, but this plugin includes his *.js and *.css files into all pages. For example, at the [page](http://essayhilfe.de/bachelorarbeit/) there isn't any forms, but you could find into source code of the page such includes:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://essayhilfe.de/app/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/js/jquery.form.min.js?ver=3.51.0-2014.06.20"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" id="contact-form-7-css"  href="http://essayhilfe.de/app/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/css/styles.css?ver=4.7" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://essayhilfe.de/app/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/js/scripts.js?ver=4.7"></script>`

How could I load this files only at specific pages?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to dequeue the scripts by name (handle) of the script.

```
wp_dequeue_script($handle);
```

Then add a page condition ,

```
if(is_page(page_id))
```

inside condition add contact form 7 scripts again by using `wp_enqueue_script` and give the plugin path so that whenever you update contact form 7 , scripts also update and work proper. Hook to use : `wp_enqueue_scripts`

Reference : [Link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/)

Answer (score 0):

This is not my code:

// Deregister Contact Form 7 styles in your functions.php for any page that isn't your contact page. (assuming your page is named contact-us)

```
add_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'aa_deregister_styles', 100 );
function aa_deregister_styles() {
    if ( ! is_page( 'contact-us' ) ) {
        wp_deregister_style( 'contact-form-7' );
    }
}
```

// Deregister Contact Form 7 JavaScript files on all pages without a form

```
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'aa_deregister_javascript', 100 );
function aa_deregister_javascript() {
    if ( ! is_page( 'contact-us' ) ) {
        wp_deregister_script( 'contact-form-7' );
    }
}
```

Code Tuts+ made a great post about this. Read it here 
https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/optimizing-contact-form-7-for-better-performance--wp-31255